# Python Scraper Output From CSV Reader Maxes Around 1000 Results Even With List Being 1000+?

Tags: python, email, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote this code in Python to take a list of 1000+ links in a csv file, search them and extract an email on the links page. However the output keeps maxing out at 1000 records even though my lists have over 1000 links. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Essentially I want to be able to use lists upwards of 5000 links/rows.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
import sys

start = time.time()

contents = []
with open('./SCLINKS.csv','r',encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvf:
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url)
for url in contents:

    try:
        html_content = requests.get(url[0]).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
        email = re.search(r'\w+@\w+\.\w+', soup.select_one('p[itemprop="description"]').text)
        print(email.group())
    except:
            pass

print('It took', time.time()-start, 'seconds.')

sys.exit()
```

Comment: Which "output" is maxing out at 1000 records? Is it the `contents` list you build from reading `SCLINKS.csv`? Hard to debug without seeing the input. Is that csv well-formed, or is there a problem after line 1000? How many lines are read from that csv? Or, are you referring to printed output from grabbing the HTML content and printing `email.group()`?

Comment: Each row of the first column is a new link. Each row looks like this https://soundcloud.com/morgana-coelho
https://soundcloud.com/labrador
https://soundcloud.com/axoffitt
https://soundcloud.com/erik-ibarra-2 
and so on all the way past the 1000th row so I don't no how the formatting would be an issue :/ and so far no matter how many rows/links I have it caps out at around 1000 every time

Comment: @sam also I'm referring to the printed output from grabbing the html content and printing email.group()

Comment: Could be soundcloud, restricting your downloads/scraping? Also, why are you getting `url[0]`, when url is one element from `contents`. Is contents not a list of urls?

Comment: I think you still need to check how large your contents array is: is that where you're hitting the 1000 limit, i.e. it's not reading in all of the rows from the spreadsheet, or is the problem in your scraping loop?

Comment: @Sam No, both the `url` variables here are really lists of strings, which is what csv.reader returns for each row in the CSV.

Comment: @Rup Its reading all the rows in the spreadsheet, but for whatever reason the output from the scraping loop only give be 1000 results. For example i'll have 2000 rows in the csv and when I copy over the output it only copies over 1000 results. I don't know if its python cutting the output at 1000 records or something wrong with the code